# Linq to Generic list C# Data Filtering issue

Tags: c#, linq, filtering, generic-programming

I am having a problem with following linq query in my c# code. I want to exclude data that has jobChangeTypeId `Unallocate` or `Delete` but its bringing them in the resultset.

```
foreach (EmployeejobAudit empjobAudit in list)
{
     int iEmployeeServiceId = empjobAudit.EmployeeServiceId;

     PushNotificationData.jobAuditRow[] jobAuditList = empjobAudit.jobAuditList;

     var jobCallQuery = (from job in jobAuditList
                         where ((from dc in dataset.jobCall select dc.jobId).Contains(job.jobId)) && 
                        ( job.jobChangeTypeId != (int) Common.jobChangeTypeId.Unallocate  || job.jobChangeTypeId != (int) Common.jobChangeTypeId.Delete)                                   
                         select job).Distinct();

     if (jobCallQuery.Any())
     {
         foreach (var item in jobCallQuery)
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("jobId {0}  Employee ServiceID {1} jobChange Type ID {2}", item.jobId, item.EmployeeServiceId, item.jobChangeTypeId);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: `!= && !=` to exclude both. You would use `==` and `||` if you wanted to include *only* those ([de morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `||` instead of `&&`. The problem is that when using `||` one of the two expressions will always be true, thus be included.

This:

```
job.jobChangeTypeId != (int) Common.jobChangeTypeId.Unallocate  
|| job.jobChangeTypeId != (int) Common.jobChangeTypeId.Delete
```

Needs to be changed to this:

```
job.jobChangeTypeId != (int) Common.jobChangeTypeId.Unallocate  
&& job.jobChangeTypeId != (int) Common.jobChangeTypeId.Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an AND not an OR if you want to exclude both of them

```
foreach (EmployeejobAudit empjobAudit in list)
{
     int iEmployeeServiceId = empjobAudit.EmployeeServiceId;

     PushNotificationData.jobAuditRow[] jobAuditList = empjobAudit.jobAuditList;

     var jobCallQuery = (from job in jobAuditList
                         where ((from dc in dataset.jobCall select dc.jobId).Contains(job.jobId)) && 
                        ( job.jobChangeTypeId != (int) Common.jobChangeTypeId.Unallocate && job.jobChangeTypeId != (int) Common.jobChangeTypeId.Delete)                                   
                         select job).Distinct();

     if (jobCallQuery.Any()) //Useless because the following foreach will do it for you, but you can test if != null 
     {
         foreach (var item in jobCallQuery)
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("jobId {0}  Employee ServiceID {1} jobChange Type ID {2}", item.jobId, item.EmployeeServiceId, item.jobChangeTypeId);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. the for loop after .Any() is just to test the result set and once it satisfies the logic I no longer need it and i use ElementAt(0) to retrieve record.

Comment: Ok but it wasn't my point. I just said that .Any() is useless because the foreach will do nothing if jobCallQuery is an empty list and that without error. But maybe there is some other code after your loop in the .Any() block.